# is it good practise to manage jwt token using jwt-blacklist or it store in db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt

I am learning nodejs and creating crud APIs using JWT tokens. so here is my question is it good practice to use jwt-blacklist instead of storing tokens in DB?

Answer (score 0):

I am speaking from my limited knowledge,  If your project is pushing (publishing)on any public site like GitHub, or any other platform , for data you must use the **. env** ( Environment variables) file to store your sensitive credentials like API keys.(DB _URI , jwt token  ) so that way you can secure the   API,
then ,
you need to **store  securely store JWTs in a cookie ?**
A JWT needs to be stored in a safe place inside the user’s browser. If you store it inside localStorage, it’s accessible by any script inside your page. This is as bad as it sounds; an XSS attack could give an external attacker access to the token.

To reiterate, whatever you do, don’t store a JWT in local storage (or session storage). If any of the third-party scripts you include in your page is compromised, it can access all your users’ tokens.

To keep them secure, you should always store JWTs inside an httpOnly cookie. This is a special kind of cookie that’s only sent in HTTP requests to the server. It’s never accessible (both for reading or writing) from JavaScript running in the browser.